# Angular Material 2 multiline select

Tags: angular-material2

Is there a way to display a multiline selectable list with Material 2? The size attribute doesn't seem to be supported by the mat-select element...

Here's what I was doing in my component before implementing Material 2:

```
<select size="10">
    <option *ngFor="let post of posts" [attr.selected]="selectedPost && post.id === selectedPost.id ? true : null" (click)="onSelect(post)">{{post.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Here's what it looks like: [list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTFaK.png)

I've also looked at mat-list, but it doesn't seem to support selection natively. So before going the custom route, I'm asking for help. It seems like a basic feature, so I'm surprised it's not available...

Comment: Looks like it's possible: https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#selection-lists

Comment: I've seen this example, but it's a multi selection with checkboxes. I need to allow only one selection and I don't want checkboxes.

Comment: Sorry I did not read correctly. Look here: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7157 it's not implemented yet but the last comment proposes a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 2+ w/Material doesn't support multiline `Selects`.

You can see the closed issue [here](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3883).

Essentially, the team said that they don't believe the Material Design spec allows for multi-line selects.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are talking about a single option in the list taking more than one line, not the whole list itself.

Comment: @MathM. Possibly. They do say "multiline select" in the title though, rather than "multiple select". Figured I'd toss up an answer in case they actually meant multi-line.